# Suppose $f \circ g(x) = \frac{x^2-6x+2}{x+1}$ and $g(x) = 1 - x$. Then $f(-1)$ is equal to...

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I tried to substitute the value of $g(x)$ to every $x$ in  $f \circ g(x) = \frac{x^2-6x+2}{x+1}$ and ended up with $\frac{x^2+4x-3}{-x+2}$.
Although honestly I do not know if that helps, or what I could do next.

I thought maybe this question just requires me to substitute $-1$ to every $x$ in $f\circ g(x) = \frac{x^2-6x+2}{x+1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $f(1-x)=\frac{x^2-6x+2}{x+1}$

Put $x=1-u$, we get:

$f(u)=\frac{(1-u)^2-6(1-u)+2}{(1-u)+1}$

Set $u=-1$, we get:

$f(-1)=\frac{2^2-2\cdot 6+2}{2+1}=\frac{-6}{3}=-2$

Comment: +1. True and untricky way :)

Answer (score 4):

It is an easy way: since $-1=g(2)$, then
$$f(-1)=f(g(2))=f\circ g(2)=\frac{-6}{3}=-2$$

Comment: You are right, almost similar to my detailed way, +1.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$f(g(2))=f(-1)$ so for $x=2$ ...

Answer (score 1):

We have \begin{align*}f(-1) &= (f \circ g)(g^{-1}(-1)) \\ &= (f \circ g)(1-(-1)) \qquad \text{(as $g^{-1}(x)=1-x$)} \\ &= \frac{2^2-6\cdot 2 + 2}{2+1} \\ &= -2\end{align*}

Comment: Hi, if it is fine, could you please elaborate on how f(-1) is equivalent to the $f∘g(x)=x2−6x+2x+1$ 
I think it would be helpful if I could get their relationship, conceptually since we are mostly just taught on how to use formulas.
Thank you!

Comment: Well, $(f\circ g)(x)$ means $f(g(x))$: that is, you put $x$ into $g$, then take the output from $g$ and input it into $f$. Now, if you take $x = g^{-1}(1)$, then $g(x) = 1$: that is what $g^{-1}$ means; it undoes $g$. Therefore, if we put $x = g^{-1}(1) = 2$ and put it into $f \circ g$, then $x$ will get put into $g$ to give $1$, then that $1$ will get put into $f$, so the result will be $f(1)$, which is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot!